# Angular Mat Menu or Mat-related wont load or show

Tags: angular

My mat menu or mat card or anything mat related i think are not working anymore. I didnt change anything but i think it happens after running these two commands because i was working on a feature and some posts say to run it. The menu wont show up, the page with mat chips wont load etc.

**npm install --save @angular/material**
and **ng add @angular/material**

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'setFocusOrigin' of undefined
    at _MatMenu._focusFirstItem (vendor.js:71210)
    at _MatMenu.focusFirstItem (vendor.js:71201)
    at MatMenuTrigger._initMenu (vendor.js:71686)
    at MatMenuTrigger.openMenu (vendor.js:71622)
    at MatMenuTrigger.toggleMenu (vendor.js:71604)
    at MatMenuTrigger._handleClick (vendor.js:71859)
    at MatMenuTrigger_click_HostBindingHandler (vendor.js:71903)
    at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (vendor.js:38693)
    at wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault (vendor.js:38728)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (vendor.js:75951)
```

I did not change any coding except for running those 2 commands.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it in case anyone has this problem, something was wrong with my material folder maybe. I copied the src folder into another fresh original template copy of the project. Deleted the copy templated src folder and moved in the src folder from the problematic project folder. Somehow it's working like normal now.